# Run a python script from another python script running as a daemon

Tags: python, python-daemon

I have a small python file which just outputs a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("This is a Test")
```

I can call this python script from another python script like so:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'myPythonFile.py'])
```

And I can see the 'This is a Test' in my source python program.

But I want to call this script from a running Daemon as described here: https://gist.github.com/andreif/cbb71b0498589dac93cb

When I put the call to

```
    subprocess.call(['python', 'myPythonFile.py'])
```

In MyDaemon.Run I DO NOT see the output.

How can I do this?

Comment: im looking at the class you linked and i notice that in the initialization it has `stdout='/dev/null'` if you dont give it a proper output it will print to null so you will never see it!

Comment: If I use print("Show something") I can see it in the console??

Comment: are you asking or are you saying? your comment is unclear

Comment: When I use print("Show something") I can see this output in the console. Do I still have to change stout to something else to see the output from my 2nd python script?

Comment: your question states that you cant see, now you can see? where can you see it and where do you WANT to see it?

Comment: If I simply use print("Something") in my original python daemon it shows on screen.  But the output of the second python scrip that I launch from the daemon does not show on screen.  I WANT to see the output from the second python script on screen.

Comment: your "second" script doesnt print to the same stdout as your daemon. just to test, try to get your second script to print into a file(use an absolute path just in case) see that it runs properly, if it does then you need to pass your second script your daemon's stdout

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `check_output` function to see the actual output in your console

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', 'myPythonFile.py'])
```

You can find more info in the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Hi, this did not make any difference. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` can send its output to a file

```
tempfile = '/tmp/output.tmp' # better use mktemp

with open( tempfile, 'w') as output:
    response = subprocess.call(
         ['python', 'myPythonFile.py'], 
         stdout=output, 
         stderr=output,
    )
with open( tempfile, 'r') as output:
    # read what happened from output, and decide what to do next
    # or perhaps just feed it into your logging system
```

Answer (score 0):

A daemon process is characterised by having no controlling terminal, because it is detached from whatever started the daemon. The daemon process is not connected to any console, by definition.

So, if that daemon runs another process:

> I want to call this script from a running Daemon

then there is still no controlling terminal, and standard output is by default connected to the null device.

You will need to have the daemon process arrange to have its output somewhere. For example, a log file.

Try [the `python daemon` library](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/) for a way to create daemons *and* nominate specific files (e.g. a log file you opened) to remain open in the daemon process.